# Not able to find the iso image path in VM

Tags: linux, rhel, mount, iso

I am trying to Configure Local Repo in my VM which has `RHEL8.X` installed using the following command.

```
[root@somaf-server ~]# mkdir -p /mnt/os
[root@somaf-server ~]# mount -o loop /root/RhelFileName.iso /mnt/os
[root@somaf-server ~]# cp -rf /mnt/os
[root@somaf-server ~]# umount /mnt/os
```

But here my issue is I am not able to find the path of `.iso` image of `RHEL8.x` even not inside `/home` directory. Can anybody help me to find the correct path of iso image so that I can create the local repo.

Comment: What is the host operating system? What virtualization software are you using? Is the iso file in a file system in the virtual machine or is it in the host operating system? Maybe you can search for the iso file via the command line `sudo find / -name '*.iso'`

Comment: I select the .iso from host operation system.

Comment: The operating system in the virtual machine does not see the file system in the host without special methods. For example, if the host is also an ssh server, you can connect to it via ssh or copy files via sftp or rsync.

Comment: I created these VM using `ESXi`.

Comment: Sorry I do not know ESXi. But RHEL should be able to run ssh. What about the host operating system? Is it your host or some server in the internet cloud? Would you be able to install an ssh server in the host operating system? Or use such a server that maybe is already there?

Comment: `cp -rf /mnt/os` is an incomplete command!